# Formatting a static AES Key for decryption in Python

Tags: python, encryption, aes

I'm working to decrypt several files in python using a given AES key via the PyCrypto AES implementation. I've currently set it to a static list of hex bytes (as this was how it was provided to me). However, when I try to decrypt the files, I get a warning stating the key size must be 16, 24, or 32 bytes. My code for converting the list to a string is as follows:

```
''.join(str(x) for x in key)
```

I've verified that the key in list form has 16 bytes, but something I'm doing when converting it must be changing the size. What operations would be best for changing a key from something like

```
[0x2a, 0x7e, 0x15, 0x16, 0x28, 0xae, 0xd2, 0xa6, 0xab, 0xf7, 0x15, 0x88, 0x09, 0xcf, 0x4f, 0x3c]
```

to a usable string for decryption?

Comment: Have you tried `''.join(chr(x) for x in key)` if you're using Python 2?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what AES implementation you're using, but the right answer is likely to look like

```
k = bytes([0x01, 0x23, 0x34, 0x56])
```

Comment: Oh, good point. I'm using PyCrypto's implementation. It takes in a bytestring. I'll update the original question to include that.

Comment: I've tried this, and it doesn't seem to work. I still get the key size error, and cannot decrypt the files.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`_key = base64.b64encode(key)`